# div on top-left and bottom-right coner of parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to position first div to top-left of parent div and second div to bottom-right of parent div . Here is my code !

```
<div class="parent"> 
<div class="tl">TopLeft</div>
<div class="br">BottomRight</div>
</div>
```

Here is my css ,

```
  .parent
    {
        width: auto;
        height:300px;
        background: Black;
    }

  .tl
  {
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  background:Aqua;
  }

 .br
  {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:Aqua;
  }
```

By my code , the topLeft div is in the correct position , but the bottom-right div is outside of parent div . Want to know what I need in my code !

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6L96/) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the parent element's position property to relative. That will make the children position themselves correctly in relation to the parent rather than the document.

```
.parent {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/dQCpy/1/

Comment: Quick and correct , so quick  +1 and quick accept :) Thanks grc !

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent
{
    width: auto;
    height:300px;
    background: Black;
    position:relative;
}
```

Parent must have a relative position.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.parent{
background-color: yellow;width: 500px;
}

.tl{
background-color: yellowgreen;float: left;width: 200px;
}
.br{
background-color: wheat;float: right;width: 100px;
}
.clr{
clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class="parent"> 
<div class="tl">TopLeft</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="br">BottomRight</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```